# Write a failing test for an action that has no route, even with asset pipeline turned on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm on rails 3.2 with the asset pipeline turned on. I'm testing for an action that I haven't built yet (TDD; trying to get the test to fail first). When I initially run the test, I get a failure as expected.

```
class AccountsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def test_my_path
    get :my_path
    puts @response.body
    assert_template :my_path
  end

end

#=> test_my_path(AccountsControllerTest): AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'my_path' could not be found for AccountsController
```

When I add the corresponding view (app/views/my_path.html.erb), I still expect the test to fail since I haven't specified a route for this action. It passes though, and I think it's because the page is being rendered by the asset pipeline. In the view I call `<%= request.fullpath %>` and that spits out `/assets?action=my_path` from the `puts @response.body` call.

When I try to access accounts/my_path in the browser, I see "No route matches [GET] "/accounts/my_path"", so I want to make sure I have a test that's failing too. Why is this happening and how should I fix the test? Should I instead be testing the route separately with assert_recognizes? For the sake of narrowing down the source of the problem, my routes file is currently empty.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Rails controller renders existing template even if there is not corresponding action defined ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action ) . This is why your test passed after you added template.

Functional tests call the controller action directly and don't go through the router. So the tests pass even if route is not defined, and does not work in browser. Use separate test cases for routes testing (or test routes in integration tests).